# Need to learn WebFocus, any good tutorials for programmers?

Tags: webfocus

I am starting to use WebFocus for a new client.  Anybody know of good WebFocus tutorials aimed at programmers?

Comment: This is an old question but I hope your WebFocus experience was less painful than mine. It would take hours to list all the bugs, deficiencies, and inconsistencies I encountered with this software.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I too realize that this is an old question but in case someone is looking I've found the documentation (free to download) found [here](http://documentation.informationbuilders.com/wf77x.asp) helpful.